# C# SSH tunnel inside a SSH tunnel

Tags: c#, networking, ssh

I have tried connecting to a SSH server using SSH.net directive in Visual Studios Windows Forms application written in C#.

I have two SSH servers (VPS) , one accepts Passwords, the other one does not accept any kind of public key, and only accepts authentication via the private key. id_rsa.ppk
I dont want to store my private key file of my second server on my Computer.

I figured out, if I was able to connect to my first server through SSH connection (using password), is it possible to create another ssh connection within the first SSH connection that would initiate to the second server,
My private key files are stored on the first server, so is it possible to authenticate to the second server using the first server?

This would certainly eliminate the need of storing private key file of second server on my laptop, so, that would help me, connect to the second server.
Plus, the second server is only listening to connections from my first server.

Can anyone guide me to write a C# code for this case? I also want to include the key files from my first server in the connection in the first server to the second server?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If there is a chance for some other way to solve this problem. I am sure I dont need it, but in case there is  no case, I would want a loop.

Comment: @John Sorry, not exactly a loop. But you understand what I mean :)

Comment: Also,  i would want the connection from my first server to second server to be permanent. IF in case I am just able to connect to my first server and the first server transfers me to the already existing connection to the second server. Is it possible?

Comment: I almost think it might be better if you establish a connection to machine A, port forward machine B through the tunnel to A, then establish a connection to machine B through the forwarded port, and use the connection to machine A to download the private key required to connect to machine B. I don't have experience with SSH.NET but I think you might struggle with other approaches given what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you elaborate it more? Please